# JQuery rule not validating input file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I´m trying to validate a field in the form with the id #frmArchivos, but when I submit the form that field doesn't  respect the rules. My form is structured as this:

```
      <form id="frmArchivos" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                    <input id="idHerramientas" value="" hidden="" readonly="" name="idHerramientas" />
                    <div class="modal-body ">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inpArchivo">Archivo:</label>
                                    <input type="file" id="inpfile" class="form-control" name="inpfile" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
       </form>
```

And my script is this:

```
$.validate({
            form: '#frmArchivos',
            rules: {
                inpfile: {
                    required: true,
                    extension: "docx|rtf|doc|pdf"
                }
            },
            messages: {  
                inpfile: {
                    required: "input type is required",
                    extension: "select valid input file format"
                }
            }
        });
```

What could be the problem? I tried with different tags like $('#frmArchivos').validate() but the console throws me an error of nodeType undefined. 
I also tried to validate trough html but it doesn´t validate the file extension when post the form.

If you need more information please tell me, and thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the next code

```js
(function () {

    var validator = null;
    var frmArchivos = $("#frmArchivos");
    var inpfile = $("#inpfile");
    
    function initializeValidation() {
      validator = frmArchivos.validate({
      rules: {
          inpfile: {
            required: true,
            extension: "docx|rtf|doc|pdf"
          }
        },
      messages: {
          inpfile: {
            required: "input type is required",
            extension: "select valid input file format"
            }
          }
        });
    }
    
    $(document).ready(function () {

       initializeValidation();
       inpfile.change(function(){
       
       //Validate field
       inpfile.valid();
       
      });

    });

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.js"></script>

<style>label.error{color: red;}</style>

<form id="frmArchivos" name="frmArchivos">
  <input id="idHerramientas" value="" hidden="" readonly="" name="idHerramientas" />
  <div class="modal-body ">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inpArchivo">Archivo:</label>
          <input type="file" id="inpfile" class="form-control" name="inpfile" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Used libraries: 
[JQuery](https://code.jquery.com/) 
[JQueryValidate](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-validate)

Comment: try with `$("#inpfile")`

Comment: Make sure you are using the libraries [JQuery](https://code.jquery.com/) and [JQueryValidate](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-validate).

Comment: i tried with everything, i have the libraries but not success. Right now i´m doing the validation by hand.

Comment: Here can you find other way to do it: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46675691/in-html-form-can-we-validate-the-text-fields-while-the-user-is-filling-in-the-f)