# In HTML form, can we validate the text fields while the user is filling in the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Is it possible to validate the text fields while user is entering the data?
For instance, If the user selects one checkbox in the form, does not enter data in the text field, and moves on to the next checkbox, the form should generate an error immediately, prompting the user to enter data for the previously selected checkbox. In other words, user will not be able to proceed unless each section
is done correctly (vs. error messages at the end of the form when the submit button is clicked)

Thank You!

Comment: do you mean triggering the js on blur / focus?

Comment: Tempted to just answer yes to this??

Comment: @tomsmithweb, can you please point me to the js reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of plugins that will do this for you.

jQuery form validation plugin: [This one is good](http://formvalidator.net/#reg-form)

If you are determined to do it manually then you would want to use something like:

```
$('input').on('change', function(){...});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples for javascript blur/focus:

https://javascript.info/focus-blur

Answer (score 1):

For something you can play with, here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/garrettascott/1u1mgkmv/) I threw together. It uses jQuery's on focus and blur events. It checks if any of the previously "required" fields were left blank (or unchecked).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function checkCheckbox(jEl) {
    return jEl.is("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
  }

  function checkTextbox(jEl) {
    return jEl.is("input[type='text']") && jEl.val() != ""
  }

  function validate(el) {
    el.parent('div')
      .prevAll('div:has(".required")')
      .add(el.parent('div'))
      .addClass('error')
      .each((i, e) => {
        jEl = $(e).children('.required');
        if (checkCheckbox(jEl) || checkTextbox(jEl)) {
          $(e).removeClass('error');
        }
      })
  }
  $(".required").on("focus blur", function() {
    validate($(this))
  });
});
```